# Identity matrices & Inverse matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm struggling with this exercise.

If

$$\begin{array}{rl} (A+I)(A-I)=O\end{array}$$

Then show that

$$\begin{array}{rl} A^{-1} = A\end{array}$$

So should I just randomly choose any matrix of A and add it with any I? Then multiply it by *A-I*? And the solution should be O? But for some reason I can't find any matrices that gives you solution: *(A+I)(A-I)=O*.

Comment: You can start by multiplying everything together and see what you get.

Comment: You cannot use any $I$. The symbol $I$ stands for the identity matrix.

Comment: Yes $I$ is the matrix with 1 along the diagonal and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that it should be $O$ (that's Ocean) on the RHS and not $0$ (that's zero)?

Comment: Yeah, indeed it's O

Answer (score 1):

If you do the multiplication of the brackets you end up with $A^2-I = 0$. 
This is only valid, if $A^2=I$.

Since, the rank of $I$ is full, so must be $A$. Therefore you can invert it and put it on the other side. You reach at $A=A^{-1}$.

Comment: There are many matrices which are their own inverses except for $I$, For example $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Oh, you are right... I'll remove that part!

Answer (score 0):

You should distribute the multiplication. Generically it's important to remember that matrix multiplication isn't commutative (so that $AB \neq BA$ in general), but this is not an issue here.

Then you should remember that one definition of the inverse of a matrix $A$ is another matrix $B$ such that $AB = I$. If you were to find such a matrix $B$ so that $AB = I$, then necessarily $B = A^{-1}$.